# Probability question/"puzzle"

Tags: probability

Given I have some number X.

I draw a random number R from the uniform distribution on the unit interval and construct two new numbers Y and Z through the following procedure:

Y = R*X

Z = X - Y

What is the probability, that neither Y or Z (not exclusive OR) are below 1? As far as I see, the probability would be $(1-\frac{2}{X})$ - is this correct?

Comment: What do we know about $X$? The result is certainly not true if $X=1!$.

Comment: Sorry, it should be that this is the probability, that NEITHER Y or Z are below 1..obviously it is not possible that neither is below one when X = 1, so the possibility would have to exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X \gt 1$ (if not, both $Y$ and $Z$ will be below $1$), $P(Y \lt 1)=\frac 1X$ and $P(Z \lt 1)= \frac 1X$.  As long as $X \gt 2$ these are disjoint and the chance that one of them is less than $1$ is $\frac 2X$.  If $1 \lt X \lt 2$ one of them is certain to be below $1$.  If $X \gt 2$, the chance that neither $Y$ nor $Z$ is less than $1$ is then $1-\frac 2X$

Comment: Thanks Ross! What about Andrés comment that it's not true if "X is big"..?

Comment: @Pegah:  I was answering the original question with "either".  For the new version, if $X$ is large (greater than $2$), I think you are right, as you fail if $R \in (0,\frac 1X) \cup (1-\frac 1X,1)$  I think André's comment was also for "either".

Answer (score 1):

If $1\lt X\lt 2 $, then the formula $1-\frac{2}{X}$ cannot possibly be correct, since a probability cannot be negative.

We want the probability that neither  $RX$ nor $(1-R)X$ is below $1$, or equivalently that both are $\ge 1$.

This is $0$ if $X\le 1$.

For $X\gt 1$, we want the probability that $R\ge \frac{1}{X}$ and $R\le 1-\frac{1}{1-X}$. If $X\lt 2$, this is impossible.

For $X\ge 2$, the probability is $\left(1-\frac{1}{X}\right)-\frac{1}{X}$, which is indeed $1-\frac{1}{X}$.

Comment: ...?It's NOT correct?

Comment: I dont see why its not correct..I go with Ross and think failure happens in 0 to 1/X or 1-1/X to 1, hence for 2/X, and hence sucess is 1- 2/X

Comment: It is correct for $X\ge 2$. Modified answer, removing reference to the "either" version.

Comment: thx, should be 1 - X/2 though.